# The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'PagedList' - VS 2019, MVC 5.2.7

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination

I am using MVC 5.2.7 and Visual Studio 2019. I have done everything which is mentioned in whole thread but still not resolve the problem.

I have try to resolve below steps

- Clean the solutions and rebuild again
- Clean temp data
- Restarted visual studio 2019
- Also try with create new project
- uninstall-package PagedList.mvc
- install-package PagedList.mvc

[image: -]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I have implemented the same and its working.
[here](https://github.com/JitanDev/MVC-PagedList/) is a sample implementation of the code I have tested into VS2019 and MVC 5.2.7 on GITHUB

Comment: Yes, I had gone through your code, it worked in my system with the same configuration but not able to figure out what was the problem. But I removed using PagedList.MVC from the main view and put it into partial view, It worked not sure what was a problem. but for a time being problem is resolved now.